# Get Map key and value from two different Map with key and vlue in java

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

There are two Map, first one contains student id and name. second one contains student id and status of 'Pass' or 'Fail'. There is a method which takes two parameters of Map type and returns Map.

```
    //1st Map
    Map<Integer, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    map1.put(1, "x");
    map1.put(2, "y");
    map1.put(3, "z");
    map1.put(4, "a");
    map1.put(5, "b");`
```

and

```
    //2nd Map
    Map<Integer, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
    map2.put(1, "fail");
    map2.put(2, "fail");
    map2.put(3, "fail");
    map2.put(4, "pass");
    map2.put(5, "pass");`

   //the method
public Map<Integer, String>findFaildStudent(Map<Integer, String>map1,Map<Integer, String>map2){
returns Map<Integer, String>;
 }
```

> So, my question is how to find the record of failed students. I did try it myself but didn't succeed. Any help is appreciated.
>
> What I tried so far

```
public Map<Integer, String>findFaildStudent(Map<Integer, String>map1,Map<Integer, String>map2){
    Integer key = null;
    String value = null;

    Iterator<Entry<Integer, String>> iterator = map1.entrySet().iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        Entry<Integer, String> next = iterator.next();
        key = next.getKey();
    }

    Iterator<Entry<Integer, String>> iterator2 = map2.entrySet().iterator();
    while(iterator2.hasNext()){
        Entry<Integer, String> next = iterator2.next();
        value=next.getValue();
    }

    Map<Integer,String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    hashMap.put(key, value);

    return hashMap;

}
```

Comment: make life simple for your self and create a class with those fields then make however many objects you want, store it into a list of some sort and query that for results.

Comment: "I did try it myself but didn't succeed". So *what* did you try? In what way did it "not succeed"?

Comment: @Blorgbeard I tried to iterate the first Map and get the key then iterate the second Map and get the value and put into a new Map and returned it from the method.

Comment: So can you show us that code, and explain what goes wrong with it?

Comment: @Aominè: I am not allowed to do what you are suggesting.

Comment: @Blorgbeard: updated!

Comment: Ok, so what goes wrong with your code? Hint: how many times is `hashMap.put` executed?

Comment: @Blorgbeard: once :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public Map<String, String> findFaildStudent(Map<Integer, String>map1,Map<Integer, String>map2){
    Map<String, String> failed = new HashMap<>();

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> k : map2.entrySet()) {
        if(k.getValue().equals("fail")){
            failed.put(map1.get(k.getKey()), map2.get(k.getValue()));
        }
    }
    return failed;
 }
//returns... ("x","failed"), ("y", "failed"), ("z", "failed")
```

So basically you just need to iterate through the 2nd map since it contain failed student, then you get the key and use that key to get the value of map1.
You cannot concate the keys because the key is unique so if you want combine both map together it is better to create another map using map1(value) as key and map2(value) as value. Hope I understand your question but if you only want map2 of failed student then try below.

```
public Map<Integer, String> findFaildStudent(Map<Integer, String>map1,Map<Integer, String>map2){
Map<Integer, String> failed = new HashMap<>();

for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> k : map2.entrySet()) {
    if(k.getValue().equals("fail")){
        failed.put(k.getKey(), map1.get(k.getKey()));
    }
}
return failed;
//returns... (1,"x"), (2, "y"), (3, "z")
```

Comment: But what about the method that I have? I mean I have to do it with that method.

Comment: so back to your question is map1 has any relation to map2?

Comment: So you are saying that I don't have to iterate over the 1st Map?

Comment: no they are not related, except they share the same key.

Comment: sorry not quite get your question here but what exactly are you expecting for return? can you give me some examples? like (x, "failed") (y, "failed) (z, "failed) or just (1, "failed), (2, "failed), (3, "failed). If you are expecting the first set then use the top (add a new map with <string, string> instead of <integer, string> and if you are expecting the 2nd set then use the bottom one.

Comment: I have to show the records of fail students by using the method which I have mentioned and I am given two Map in which 1st one contains id and name while the 2nd one contains id and status. Also both Map share the same key.

Comment: should just say so...check the 2nd method again

Comment: Oh ! it worked. Thank you zillion times :) However the 1st one is not working , so you can updated your answer.

Answer (score -2):

```
map1.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(entry -> "fail".equals(map2.get(entry.getKey())))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> e.getValue()));
```